# Automatically detect discrete or continuous palette in custom ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on developing a package called `ipeaplot` for theme and palette standardization. One of the attempts we made was to create a `scale_color()` function capable of distinguishing whether the user passed a continuous or discrete column (for example, if the column class is numeric or integer, then the scale selection should be continuous, otherwise it should be discrete)

Below is the code example

```
# Install package
remotes::install_github("ipeadata-lab/ipeaplot")
library(ggplot2)
library(ipeaplot)
```

This code works, but see that I have to specify that what I want is a continuous scale

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = gear)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_ipea(discrete = F)
```

This code returns the following error: "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale"

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = as.character(gear))) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_ipea(discrete = T)
```

So I need to manually set `scale_color_ipea(discrete = T)` but I would like the function to automatically detect the class of the column and user an adequate color scale accordingly.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = as.character(gear))) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_ipea(discrete = T)
```

Would anyone have a tip on how this could be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would leave room for extending your package here by getting `scale_color_ipea` to create an S3 class object, and then define a `ggplot_add` method.

This mechanism allows you to interrogate the plot object to fully automate the selection of discrete or continuous scales based on the data type.

```r
scale_color_ipea <- function(discrete = FALSE, ...) {
  structure(list(...), class = "scale_chooser")
}

ggplot_add.scale_chooser <- function(object, plot, name) {
  args <- object
  var <- rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::quo_squash(plot$mapping$colour), plot$data)
  discrete <- !is.numeric(var)
  if(discrete) {
    return(plot + 
             do.call("discrete_scale",
                     c(list(aesthetics = "color", scale_name = "ipea", 
                     palette = colorRampPalette(c("red", "green", "blue"))),
                     args)))
  }
  return(plot + 
           do.call("continuous_scale", 
                   c(list(aesthetics = "color", scale_name = "ipea", 
                   palette = function(x) {
                     colorRamp(c("red", "green", "blue"))(x) |>
                       apply(1, \(x) do.call("rgb", as.list(x/255)))
                   }), args, guide = "colourbar")))
}
```

This now allows:

```r
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = gear)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_ipea()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = factor(gear))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_ipea()
```

[image]

There are some caveats here. A full implementation would probably need to iterate backwards through all the layers in the plot object, in case color is only defined after the base ggplot call (which happens frequently). Each layer would need its `mapping` and `data` assessed to determine if a color is specifically mapped there rather than inherited. In a real world implementation you would of course separate out your discrete and continuous palette functions too to keep your code neat and flexible.

Comment: that's a very thorough answer! However, I have the impression very often users pass data and `aes` to the `geom_` layer. Like `geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = gear))`.  What would need to be changeg in your solution to make it work in cases like this?

Comment: @rafa.pereira yes, I mention that at the end of my answer and how you would deal with it (iterating backwards through the layers and finding which are mapped to color)

Comment: yes, your response was very upfrot about that, butI don't understad how one to 'iterate backwards through the layers'

Comment: @rafa.pereira inside `ggplot_add` we have access to the ggplot object itself. This has a member called `layers` which contains the geom objects, each of which has a `mapping` object containing the information put into `aes`. So we could do `for(i in seq_along(plot$layers)) {` and extract the data/aesthetic information for each `plot$layers[[i]]` like I did for the whole plot in the code above. The full implementation would be quite time-consuming, but I think I have spelled it out well enough for someone who is skilled enough to write their own package to implement it themselves.

Comment: thanks! That's very clear! upvoting !

Comment: That's very clear. Thank you very much for the complete answer and the clarifications made later.